# How can I insert time data into a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a while loop `L<=100`, and each time the mouse changes the position I take the time:

```
[newX,newY,newbutton]= GetMouse (window); % Controls mouse position 

if  ((newX~=xCenter )||( newY~=yCenter)) &&  (elapsed_Response_latency==0);
elapsed_Response_latency=toc;
```

How can I save all of the `elapsed_Response_latency` at each loop? Currently, it overwrites the time at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make `elapsed_response_Latency` an empty array that will be populated for later.  Next, at each mouse click, simply **concatenate** the results to the array.  Also, I would recommend you **change** your logic so that you obtain the latency first, check to see what the latency is, and **then** add this to the array.  I **think** this is what you are trying to do (correct me if I'm wrong).  So do this:

```
elapsed_Response_latency = [];

%// Further set up...

% // Start loop ...

    [newX,newY,newbutton]= GetMouse (window); % Controls mouse position 

    t = toc; %// Save time here
    if  ((newX~=xCenter )||( newY~=yCenter)) && (t == 0)
        elapsed_Response_latency = [elapsed_Response_latency t]; %//NEW
    end
```

The reason why we need to change the logic is because `elapsed_Response_latency` is now going to be an array, and so if you tried doing `elapsed_Response_latency == 0`, you would be comparing **all** elements to zero, and that's probably not what your goal is. At each iteration, every time you perform a mouse click, we **stack** the results together horizontally should your mouse position move.

---

However, because you have a `while` loop with a pre-established number of times you are running the loop, when it comes to memory and accessing, MATLAB recommends that you **pre-allocate** the array before you use it.  Therefore, initialize your array so that it's just a bunch of -1s and there are 100 of them in total.  The reason why I say -1 is because at each iteration, if we don't pass the condition in your `if` statement, these particular locations will remain -1 so it'll be easier for us to filter out.  If we made them something like zero, there is a possibility that you could have a latency of 0 (perhaps), and so you want to take these into account.

In any case, inside your `while` loop, index into the specific location in this array using an index associated with the `while` loop and go from there.  Something like this:

```
L = 1;
num_iterations = 100;
elapsed_Response_latency = -1*ones(1,num_iterations);

while L <= num_iterations

    %// Do some stuff

    %// Your code
    [newX,newY,newbutton]= GetMouse (window); % Controls mouse position 

    t = toc; %// Save time here
    if  ((newX~=xCenter )||( newY~=yCenter)) && (t == 0)
        elapsed_Response_latency(L) = t; %//NEW
    end
    L = L + 1; %// Increment counter
end

%// Filter out bad times
elapsed_Response_latency(elapsed_Response_latency == -1) = [];
```

However, if you want to see the cases when the mouse didn't move or if the latency wasn't long enough, you can leave the -1s in there, or don't do the last statement in the above code.  The -1 will tell you when the particular condition failed for an iteration.

Comment: It shouldn't. The second is essentially identical to the first. Either way, thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: where is the `tic` ? in the `GetMouse` function ?

Comment: @Hoki probably. I only used what the OP gave me. I'm sure it's somewhere in his code that he didn't give me.

Comment: @Hoki tic is the first function under while L <= num_iterations